# CORS Error When adding Authorization header

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, cors, authorization-header

I'm building an Angular app that calls a .Net Core webapi. I have been able to set it up to be able to successfully call back and get a response with using CORS. But when I add the Authorization header to the Angular interceptor it throws the following error.

**Error**
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:57120/api/values' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**C# Startup - Configure method**

```
app.UseCors(
            options =>
            {
                options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
                options.WithHeaders("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"); 
                options.AllowCredentials();
            }
        );
```

**Angular HttpInterceptor**

```
const token =  localStorage.getItem('access-token');
    
const clone = request.clone({
      headers: request.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token),
      withCredentials: true,
      
});

return next.handle(clone);
```

Comment: Can you verify that headers are being returned in postman? Note that if your code breaks before headers are sat then you will get cors error instead of http error

Comment: I've never used Postman. I can try to figure it out.

Comment: So here's a kicker, my work blocks postman. But from what I can tell there doesn't appear to be any errors being thrown. It works without the line to add the authorization header, and doesn't when I add it.

Comment: sanity check on your middleware order: is your CORS middleware before your authorization middleware (it should be)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a wrong startup configuration . Try to use a named cors policy and change your app.UserCors to anotner syntax:

```
  app.UseCors("CorsPolicy") 

services.AddCors(opt =>  opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", c =>
            { 
                c.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            }));
```

If it works you then can replace c.AllowAnyOrigin() by options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");

Comment: I still used the app.UseCors() method, but included the same options as you have.  I gave you the answer because it works.  Thank you again.